# How to get the list of all changed files in SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to get the list of all the files which I have changed till now from initial code which I first checked in to SVN (the initial code). Is there any way to get this list in SVN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Tortoize svn then :
 Right click on your folder
 Show log
 right click on your last revision
 compare with previous version
 and choose the two versions you want to compare ( basically 1 and last )

Hope that's help

Comment: When I am comparing my last revision to 1st revision, I am getting the list of 65 files but when I am comparing my last revision to 2nd revision, I am getting 69 files. Why?

Comment: Cause you probably add some files at the second revision... check the modifications details for more informations.